# Websocket to HTML5 Outputs NaN values

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, websocket, arduino

I'm working on an Arduino temperature sensor using Websocket on my server-end and HTML5 for my client end. Everything runs smoothly but I keep getting NaN values when I try to output my temperature readings to the webpage. My web console receives outputs but I can seem to get the values to display.

```
function doSocketMessage( mess ) {

    console.log(mess.data)

    var parts = mess.data;

    var data = parts.split(",");

    var humidity = document.querySelector( '#weather > p:nth-child( 2 )' );

    var temp = document.querySelector( '#weather > p:nth-child( 1 )' );

    // Check for sensor errors
    if( data[0] == 'E' ){
        temp.innerHTML = 'Message';
        humidity.innerHTML = 'Message';
    }else{
        // Populate temperature
        temp.innerHTML = 'Temperature: ' + parseFloat( data[0] ) + '&deg;F';
        // Populate humidity
        humidity.innerHTML = 'Humidity: ' + parseFloat( data[1] ) + '%';
    }
}
```

Comment: post output of `console.log(mess.data)` as well

Comment: @satendra this is the output I get http://imgur.com/a/jFfyC

Comment: As i can see console output your data is not separated by ` , ` but you are splitting it with ` , ` .  if it is then also your `data[0]` will give you a string i.e `Tempreture :20.00` and such string can not parse into float. can you post output of `console.log("mess: ", mess)` also then i can able to provide solution

Comment: Also check what is the value of  `console.log("data[0]", data[0])`. before parsing to float

Comment: This is the output I got using `console.log("mess: ", mess)` http://imgur.com/a/CyEz5

Comment: Also with `console.log("data[0]", data[0])` this is what i got http://imgur.com/a/K4BZv

Comment: @satendra Thanks so much. I figured it out. You were right my serial output to `data[0]` was wrong. I had to strip off `Temperature` and send only figures. It's all good now.